# vertical align middle form just like text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertical align my form the same way I vertical aligned my text on my website. but it's not working, what should I do?

[image]

I would love for it to be like this:

[image]

This is my code http://pastebin.com/FuCNwM6e

```
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>2 Column CSS Layout</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin:20px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Sans",Geneva,Verdana,sans-serif;
    background-color:#555
}

div {
    text-align:center
}

#page {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:755px;
    padding:0 10px
}

#header {
    border-bottom:0px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px
}

/* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
#nav {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#nav ul {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc
}

#nav li {
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block
}

#nav li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#069;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc
}

#nav li a:hover {
    color:#c00;
    background-color:#fff
}

/* End navigation bar styling. */

#content {
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
}

#content p {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#footer {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    font-size:9pt
}

#footer p {
float: right;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}



</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div style="float: left;">
Please Login
            </div>
        </div>


        <div id="content">
<p>
<form action="" method="post">    
<label for="un">Username</label>
  <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="username" /><br/>
    <label for="pw">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="password" /><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
</p>  
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
<div style="float: right;"> copyright 2014 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your code sample on here.

Comment: I am unsure how to do that without indenting 150 lines of code manually 4 spaces?

Comment: Try setting up your code in a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can actually help you

Comment: I always thought pastebin would be enough, thanks for that little hint!

Comment: @BrianCherdak, highlight the code after you paste it and press CTRL + K to indent it.  I asked you to post it because 1) the goal of the site is to have the content even after third party sites may be shut down, and 2) some of us are behind proxies during the day, which block sites like pastebin.

Comment: @BrianCherdak select the code, then hit the `{}` button on the editor and it will indent it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS like this (I have added a 500px height for visualization)

```
body {
    margin:20px;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color:#555;
    height:100%;
}
div {
    text-align:center
}
#page {
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    width:755px;
    padding:0 10px;
}
#header {
    border-bottom:0px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px
}
/* Begin Navigation Bar Styling */
#nav {
    text-align:center;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#nav ul {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:11px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#f2f2f2;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc
}
#nav li {
    margin:auto;
    display:inline-block
}
#nav li a {
    display:block;
    padding:8px 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:700;
    color:#069;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc
}
#nav li a:hover {
    color:#c00;
    background-color:#fff
}
/* End navigation bar styling. */
#content {
    height: 500px;
    width:100%;
    background:none repeat scroll 0 0 none;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
#content p {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#footer {
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    font-size:9pt
}
#content:before {
    content:'';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: -0.25em;
    /* Adjusts for spacing */
}
#footer p {
    float: right;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
form {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: #a0a0a0 solid 1px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
}
```

[See fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgj10rkr/)

By using the flex display, we can align elements in any possible way while keeping responsiveness, so this will work with both fixed and responsive approaches, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

Put your `<form>`, inside a `<div>` and give it an id `#myForm`:

```
<div id="myForm">
  <p>
    <form action="" method="post">
      <label for="un">Username</label>
      <input type="text" id="un" placeholder="username" />
      <br/>
      <label for="pw">Password</label>
      <input type="password" id="pw" placeholder="password" />
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </p>
</div>
```

In CSS use `top: __%` to adjust the alignment, the way you want:

```
#myForm {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    left: 42%;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/zngz9hwf/11/embedded/result/) on Fiddle[Edited]

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to vertically align the `form` in the middle of `#content` -

```
#content form {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aniskhan001/act5owy3/1/)**